# how to custumize ubuntu 12.04 after installing NVIDA driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, interface, nouveau, myunity

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and install MyUnity tool. I was able to customize the interface but after I installed the NVIDIA Driver a lot of changes to the interface happens. Some changes are good when it comes to the quality of icons but other things went too ugly (example: the workspace switcher popup "ctrl+alt+up/down").

Now I want to either be able to customize the interface with MyUnity or similar tools because it's giving me this message "Your Ubuntu 12.04 is running in 2D mode. Many features will not be available"
or I want to get back my default graphic card "nouveau".

Answer (score 0):

1-Go to **Ubuntu Software Center** and install **Cairo-Dock OpenGL** , **The Myunity tool , Compiz and Compizconfig Settings Manager**

2-From the applications launcher select startup applications and add `usr/bin/cairo-dock`

3-Launch the MyUnity tool and select hidden for the launcher behavior

4-Resatart the machine

5-At the log in name there is a circle spot select it and choose cairo dock.please don't

choose 2d mode also don't choose cairodock with unity

6-Have fun with Cairo dock themes and compiz settings manager effects